# Reset the origin of a date explanatory variable in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to perform a simple linear regression on a dataset that uses a date range as the independent variable.  I want to plot the data along with the regression line and equation. The dataset is not a time series.  When I create the plot, it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjzsT.png).

The plot looks fine, however the slope is clearly not zero and the intercept should not be 0.945 as the equation states.  This [article](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65900/does-it-make-sense-to-use-a-date-variable-in-a-regression) gives a good explanation about how the programming language will shift the origin of the date range to a pre-specified zero starting point, which I believe is 1/1/1970 in R.  I think this is what is happening in my case. While the article gives a good explanation of the problem, it's solution doesn't detail how to fix the problem in R.  So my question is, how do I shift the origin of my independent variable from 1/1/1970 to the first date in my dataset when performing the linear regression in R?

I've tried converting the date range to both numeric and factor, neither of which was the solution.  I suspect that I'm not using the right search terms when searching for solutions on the web.  Most of what comes up describes how to force the regression line through the origin, which is not what I want to do here.  Thanks for the help.

EDIT:  My code to produce the plot is below.  'agcy' is a sample of the data.  The actual dataset has more than a thousand points.

```
agcy <- data.frame(as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2011-02-01', '2012-11-18', '2016-08-30', '2017-04-21')), c(-0.3, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.4))
colnames(agcy) <- c('Date', 'Diff')

png('C:\\Desktop\\file.png', width = 720, height = 480)

samps <- 0.05
MA <- movAvg(agcy, agcy$Diff, samps)  #movAvg() is a user-defined function that computes the moving average of the data series, "samps" is the proportion of data points to use in the moving average calculation

model <- lm(MA ~ agcy$Date)
intercept <- round(coef(model)[1],3)
slope <- round(coef(model)[2],3)
r2 <- round(summary(model)$r.squared,3)
eqn <- sapply(c(bquote(italic(y) == .(slope)*italic(x) + .(intercept)),bquote(r^2 == .(r2))), as.expression)
plot(agcy$Date, MA, xlab='Date',ylab='Difference',col = 'green', type = 'p', pch=18, ylim = c(-0.5,0.5))
abline(model)
text(par('usr')[2],c(0.5,0.45),eqn,pos = 2)
abline(h=0, col = 'black')

dev.off()
```

Comment: Could you include some sample data and the code you used to perform the regression, plot the data, and plot your regression line?

Comment: First, for the slope- I think your plot slope is showing zero because you created slope and rounded it to 3. Second- do you need to shift the intercept variable for any particular reason, or would something like `predict(model, data.frame(Date = as.Date("2000/1/1")))` do to just pull the predicted value at your year of interest?

Comment: I see what you mean about the slope.  I guess the slope would be the same whether the range was 2010-2017 or 1970-2017.  It does matter about the intercept, though, which the plot shows it crossing at about -0.1, and not 0.945.  I'm not trying to predict any certain point.  I just need to know the slope and intercept over the range of data that I have.  I have multiple datasets similar to this one and my goal is to compare the trends from each dataset.

Comment: Well, the "intercept" on the plot at roughly -0.1 is just where it runs into the plot boundary- it's not the actual intercept. If you extend your plot `xlim` values (with something like `xlim = c(as.Date('1965/1/1'), as.Date("2017/1/1"))`) you **should** see that the `abline` from model actually passes through 0.945 around 1970 (untested of course, as I don't have your full data). If you just use `predict()` as above, you are essentially just grabbing the model value at that crossing- the "2000/1/1" intercept, in the example above.

Comment: OK, I'm following you now.  I was unaware of the predict() function before now, but this is a convenient workaround to get the intercept value at the first point (which happens to be -0.16) and gets me the answer that I need.  Just to satisfy my curiosity, though, is there any way to just shift the origin in a linear regression from zero to some other value?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do that, but I am far from an expert! Perhaps you could make dummy variables starting at 0 and increasing sequentially with your dates, then fit a model to that. However, I would personally not worry about it since `predict()` (or just using a formula based on your `lm()` model) can easily pull out a useful reference for comparing your different data.

Comment: Thanks for your help!